# SciFi book about kids who live through a time where a plague/virus kills and takes over humans while keeping their memories

Tags: story-identification, books

Read 2017-2020

Science fiction book about kids who live through a time where this plague/virus takes over humans.

The virus basically kills the person and takes the form of them but has all the person's memories. At one point, I remember the virus took over a girl who was the daughter of a military captain of a ship. When the virus takes over the girl, she goes on a ship and passes the scan saying she did not have the virus, but then they find out and they question her. She says the virus doesn't want to hurt people, but they have no choice, saying they work with the human they take over.

- Near future/Post apocalyptic
- At one point a boy and his friend hide behind an old abandoned car.
- I remember one of the main characters to be a boy.
- The book was written from different points of view from different characters.
- I feel like the cover had a silhouette of a ruined city on it
- I don't know if this will help but I read it as an e-book on [Sora](https://soraapp.com/welcome).

It is **not** the following books:

- The Girl Who Owned a City
- The Puppet Masters
- The Host
- Plague Land
- Clay's Ark